# How do I do proper IO::Select error handling?

Tags: perl, select, io

I'm going through docs and howtos I'm finding on proper usage of IO::Select in terms of network socket communications. I think I've got my head wrapped around most of it.

However, I'm still kind of fuzzy on proper error handling. Say I've something similar to the following code running inside an object. Yes, I do realize it's messy, I should integrate IO::Select into the object and not the socket fh itself, I shouldn't recreate the IO::Select each time through the loop, I'm iterating over what can only ever be a single returned filehandle, etc. However, this keeps the example simple.

This is just a client connecting to a server, but one which I want to be able to properly handle network level errors such as packet loss.

Edit: `$self->sock()` returns just an opened IO::Socket::INET socket.

```
sub read {
    my $self = shift;
    my($length) = @_;   ### Number of bytes to read from the socket

    my $ret;

    while (length($ret) < $length) {
        my $str;

        use IO::Select;
        my $sel = IO::Select->new($self->sock());

        if (my @ready = $sel->can_read(5)) {  ### 5 sec timeout
          for my $fh (@ready) {
            my $recv_ret = $fh->recv($str, $length - length($ret));
            if (!defined $recv_ret) {
              MyApp::Exception->throw(
                message => "connection closed by remote host: $!",
              );
            }
          }
        }
        else {
          ### Nothing ready... we timed out!
          MyApp::Exception->throw(
                  message => "no response from remote host",
             );
        }
        $ret .= $str;
      }

      return $ret;
}
```

- Do I need to be checking the return from recv, or are errors that would affect it going to be showing up in the IO::Select object?
- Am I properly handling timeouts, or is my logic set up wrong?
- IO::Socket makes mention of an exception existing on a socket filehandle, for out of band errors and other issues. Should I be checking this in the event of a timeout? How? Or is it unimportant and OK to ignore?
- Are there any other exception cases I should be handling for proper behavior?

Comment: Why do you expect a "minimal length" of data to gather? And if sock() returns an array of filehandles, you'll get a mix of responses from all sockets in random order -- is that OK?

Comment: I expect a minimal length of data to gather because this remote host is responding to a command. Instead of shifting off the entire buffer, I'm just shifting off a byte to determine the length of the following chunk, a the chunk, and continuing till I get to the end of communication encoding.

Answer (score 1):

1) I would check just in case. When it comes to select(2), [defensive programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) is your friend.

2) Suppose you need 2048 bytes and remote host sends a byte every 5 seconds. You've just hung for 10K seconds = 3 hours. Is that what you want?

I would use `alarm 5` and `$SIG{ALRM} = sub {$stop = 1;}` instead.

3 and 4) From my experience, just `read() while select()` does the job but I can't give a sure answer here.

Comment: 2) The remote host should be sending all the bytes I need as a single communication, so this shouldn't apply. I'm actually using an alarm throwing an exception currently now, which works; it logs and throws timeout exceptions, but I'm trying to troubleshoot a intermittent hang.

Comment: If you need just a single communication, why use loop at all? You either get `$length` bytes, or you don't.

Comment: Because it can be fragmented? Packets can drop? If I'm expecting 10k chars, I wait till the socket's ready to read, and try reading 10k, and I only get a packet's worth of 1.5k chars, I need to wait to see if more packets come in and reread, don't I?